# how to eagerly load 2 layers wrapped items into a collection (entity framework C#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, iqueryable

Working on a WPF app using Entity Framework.

My entity classes are a below:

```
 public partial class Pan
    {
...
public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements{ get; set; }
...
    }


  public partial class Element
    {
...
public Pan Pan { get; set; }
public Tray Tray { get; set; }
...
    }

public class Tray
    {
...
public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements{ get; set; }
...
    }
```

I do not manage to load the list of elements with a non null Tray.

```
 new Context().Elements.Where(i => <my_filter>);
```

-> loads lazily -> tray   = null while I do want the Tray to be loaded!

```
new Context().Elements.Where(i => <my_filter>).Include(i => i.Tray).ToList();
```

-> this works fine

OK. Now I need to get the elments of a specific Pan and this brings my unsolved problem.
myPan.Elements is an ICollection and not an IQueryable.
So I cannot use .Include() method.

My conversion tries did not work:

```
myPan.Elements.AsQueryable<Element>().Where(i =>  <my_filter>).Include(i => i.Tray).ToList();
```

It runs but still loads lazily.

Any idea?

Comment: Is `myPan` a variable? Where it comes from?

Comment: myPan is an instance of Pan

Comment: Obviously. The question was *where it comes from*, i.e. how you get it, is it a proxy class instance attached to some context etc.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes  it is a proxy instance attached to a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not forced to use the navigation properies of your loaded entity, you can utilize your second (and working) solution with additional filter like this:

```
new Context().Elements.Where(i => i.Pan.Id == myPan.Id && <my_filter>).Include(i => i.Tray).ToList();
```

or if you prefer, with just inserted `Where` which is the same:

```
new Context().Elements.Where(i => i.Pan.Id == myPan.Id).Where(i => <my_filter>).Include(i => i.Tray).ToList();
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you. :)
This is actually the solution I found out after posting. I was curious  if there is a more elegant solution piping a Linq command.